# Wrong HTML response - ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

From admin side, I was getting rich text output from ckeditor tool.
Refer following image for this purpose.

[image]

In this if I use **Comic Sans MS** font then at response its giving me response like this, please see following image:

[image]

In response, I was getting **Comic Sans MS, Cursive** but this font I have not used at input time.

So what to do in this situation?

Comment: Can you add the version of `ckeditor` that you are using?

Comment: ckeditor version is 4.6.1

Comment: Also provide the plugin that you are using for the fonts, please

Comment: Basically I was loading response given by server into web view so at which place  I can find font plugin information which is current running?

Comment: Yes, it does....in order to reproduce the issue, go to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/21phL1at/6/  choose the `Comic Sans` font, and write some text...then click on the button `Get Html from CKEditor`

Comment: In that also I am getting "Cursive" written with Comic Sans font.

Comment: Yes, it's the expected behavior...so in `input time` `Comic Sans MS, Cursive` get stored :)

Comment: so what is solution for this? I can't able to get your last reply :)

Comment: Look, there is not a problem at all, it's an expected behavior...first you where thinking that it was an issue but it wasn't...actually when you choose `Comic Sans` in the `ckeditor` and you save that html, it is saved as `Comic Sans MS, Cursive`...it works that way, and actually the response is ok....

Comment: By this kind of change, actual output is different compare to target so what to do in this situation? I want to use Comic Sans not Cursive font.

Comment: This is useless....

Comment: Yes I understand this now.

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks to **Hackerman** for his help to reach at conclusion.

Basically this is not an error from ckeditor side. They are giving multiple fonts in response so whichever available via system that get used.
See following image for this purpose:

[image]

They have returned font Comic Sans MS and Cursive too. So its based on availability of font with running environment system.

In my iOS project I have added font files for **Comic Sans MS** font then its get directly loaded as like its showing in rich text input box.

Comment: Yes, that's it, exactly...basically in the jsfiddle that I build for you where you can inspect like `on live` the generated html on `ckeditor` it was just to explain you this same thing-behavior... good!

Comment: Really thanks for your help, I have updated answer too :)

Comment: I am glad to help :)